# nvcc fatal : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_80'

Tags: ubuntu, gpu, nvidia, caffe, nvcc

I am tring to **make** the **[caffe](https://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html)** ,but got the nvcc `fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_80'` error. I have the following configuration.

```
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
$ uname -m
x86_64
```

[image]

I was following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69865825/nvcc-fatal-unsupported-gpu-architecture-compute-86), its seems like upgrading the CUDA version and `export` the paths (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `PATH` , `CUDA_HOME`) done the trick. But I am using the latest CUDA version and done all the path exporting also. It looks like gpu architecture is also there -

```
$ nvcc --help

--gpu-architecture <arch> 

  Allowed values for this option:  'all','all-major','compute_50','compute_52',
 'compute_53','compute_60','compute_61','compute_62','compute_70',
'compute_72','compute_75','compute_80','compute_86','compute_87',
'compute_89','compute_90','compute_90a','lto_50','lto_52','lto_53',
'lto_60','lto_61','lto_62','lto_70','lto_72','lto_75','lto_80','lto_86',
'lto_87','lto_89','lto_90','lto_90a','native','sm_50','sm_52','sm_53',
'sm_60','sm_61','sm_62','sm_70','sm_72','sm_75','sm_80','sm_86','sm_87',
'sm_89','sm_90','sm_90a'.
```

Right now, I am just really confused and don't understand what I am missing here. Should I downgrade the CUDA version or are there any other solutions available? any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem was with the `Makefile.config` file. For some reason, all the `CUDA_ARCH:` `-gencode` was disabled in the `Makefile.config`  file.

[image]

I have enabled all the `CUDA_ARCH:` `-gencode` and tried to make it again but there was another `nvcc fatal` error, `nvcc fatal : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_30'`. What I have did, simple removed this `-gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \` from the `Makefile.config` file and added my required `-gencode`.

[image]

And this time it works!!!!

[image]